# How are initial conditions of systems found?

Tags: experimental-physics

In order to get a complete picture of the time evolution of a system, you must know the initial conditions. How do scientists find these conditions in an experimental setting?

Comment: I suppose it depends on the situation, but in general you can either measure it, prepare it, or guess it. Some combination of these is typically used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a standing challenge for science, so it is an excellent question.

The fundamental answer is that you measure the initial conditions that you care about.  Whether its temperatures or sizes or masses or specific impulses, you measure it.

Now this comes with a few quirks which makes the question interesting.  There *is* an assumption that the state of the experiment is the same as (or at least related to) the state of the experiment when it was measured.  The validity of this assumption is based on previous experiments.  We have found that *generally speaking*, objects don't gain mass when we're not looking at them, so if you measure the mass of a reagent before the experiment, it's probably the same mass when the experiment starts (unless you spill some).

However, for some objects, this doens't work.  For example, a mass of water will slowly evaporate, decreasing the mass of water.  If there's too much time between your measurement and the start of your experiment, then your initial conditions are *different* than those you measured.  To deal with this, we typically run experiments to model the behavior of this change.  For example, we can run experiments and do calculations to determine *how fast* the water evaporates.  Then, if we know how long it was between the measurement of the water's mass and the start of the experiment, then we can reliably predict the mass of water at the start of the experiment.

For some variables, they simply change too fast and too unpredictably for such modeling.  For this, we apply statistics.  We assume that the initial conditions can be modeled as a combination of predictive equations and "random variables" whose values are not known, but are expected to be statistically distributed according to a known distribution (again, verified by other experiments).  For example, in rocketry, the burn time of a solid booster is not easily measured ahead of time.  It's too dependent on lots of little factors, like how the grains were packed.  However, we can provide a distribution for that burn time (something like a Gaussian distribution with a mean of 60s and a standard deviation of 3 seconds).

We then design experiments such that those random unknown factors can be treated statistically.  For example, we might run the same experiment 20 times.  We then analyze the results of the experiment using statistics.

There's another quirk, which can be even more tricky to manage.  When you take a measurement, you always perturb the system.  If you measure the temperature of some water, you change that temperature *slightly* as some heat transfers from the water into the thermometer.  We generally try to avoid this being an issue, so measurements are chosen to have one of two behaviors:

- The change caused by the measurement is very minimal, small enough to be excluded.  As an example, measuring mass on a balance typically changes the mass of the object by a *very very* small amount, so we can ignore it.

  - The definition of "minimal" varies from situation to situation.  For exampel, the loss of mass when measuring isn't ignored by the metrologists who manage the IPK (International Kilogram Prototype) whose mass *is* the definition of a kilogram.  Those metrologists pay attention to the fact that just cleaning the IPK in preparation for measuring it decreases its mass due to abrasion against the soft cloth.  The IPK is slowly losing mass on the order of micrograms per year.  Those metrologists are actually interested in quantifying such losses!
- The thing being measured is in a "steady" state, such that if it is perturbed lightly, it will return to its previous state.  As an example, you might measure the height of water in a glass by lowering a probe into that glass until it touches liquid.  The act of touching the liquid perturbs the system -- it creates ripples.  However, it is assumed that if you wait long enough after measurement, those ripples will slowly fade away until the level of the water is smooth once again.

  - Often this process has to be treated statistically.  Sometimes you don't know how much energy you can put into a system and have it return to the same steady state.  For example, you can push on the top of a glass a little, and it returns, but push on it hard and the glass tips over and breaks.  If the glass was already wobbling back and forth, you might not know whether your push will tip it over the edge or not.  Thus, this gets handled statistically based on the probability of tipping it over (and again, that probability is calculated by past experiments)

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the practical challenges of performing experiments and people meet it in varied ways.

Suppose I want to test whether a solid disk or a hoop rolls faster down a slope (a nice demo for the introductory course). The initial conditions require that the two object be at the top of the ramp and stopped simultaneously. **I put them there, hold them still, and let go of them at the same time.** I have created the initial conditions.

If I want to test that their respective accelerations agree with the theory, I need to know the angle of the ramp. **So I get a protractor and check it.** I have measured the initial conditions.

If I want to set a practical limit on how far an explosion might scatter debris, **I would set off some test blasts, and either simple accept the longest achieved range (perhaps times a fudge factor) as an estimator or fit the distribution as a function of distance and an answer from the fit.** Here I have assumed that a large enough set of unknown initial conditions include a good estimate to the ones that I wanted.